# How to manage data types between angular2 Services call and component?

Tags: angular

I have developed a service which return type is Object:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {ClientApi} from '../shared/sdk/services';
import {CategoryApi} from '../shared/sdk/services';
@Injectable()
export class CategoryService {
public categoriesList;
name = '';

constructor(private category: CategoryApi, private userApi: ClientApi) {}

getCategories(){
        this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).subscribe((data) => {
        this.categoriesList = data;
            console.log("type : " + typeof(this.categoriesList));
            console.log ("data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
}
```

In a ts component file, I call this service:

```
    import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {CategoryService} from './category.service'

@Component({
    selector: 'category',
    templateUrl: './category.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./category.component.css'],
    providers: [CategoryService]
})

export class CategoryComponent {

    public categories;

    constructor(categoryService: CategoryService)
    {
        this.categories = categoryService.getCategories();
        console.log ("categories: " + this.categories);

    }

}
```

the variable data that I have in my service is of **Object** type and on my component ts file, I have an **undefined** type. The consequence is that the HTML file cannot read the component properties.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess what you want is

```
getCategories(){
        return this.category.find({where: {clientId: this.userApi.getCurrentId()}}).map((data) => {
        this.categoriesList = data;
            console.log("type : " + typeof(this.categoriesList));
            console.log ("data:" + JSON.stringify(data));
        return data;
    }, err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

and then use it like

```
categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(data => this.categories = data)
```

or

```
<div *ngFor="let c of categoryService.getCategories() | async">...</div>
```

You can't get the data outside of a `map()`, `subscribe()` or any other operator. Once you make an async call, this call stays async, no way around that.

Comment: What I want to do is to have a service that gets the Data coming from the backend and put this is whatever format. If I start a getCategories() | async, will I face low latency when showing ? I do not want, of course call the GetCategories() each time. Considering the code you provided, I am getting : **Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module**

Comment: `getCategories() | async` only calls `getCategories()` once.

Comment: Considering the code you provided, I am getting : **Return type of public method from exported class has or is using name 'Observable' from external module** – an idea?

Comment: No, I don't know this error message. What code line exactly is shown to cause this error? Perhaps you need to define a return type of `getCategories() : Observable<Category> { ... }` or similar (I'm not using TS actively myself)

Comment: Data is passed from the service to the Component as I have written: 'this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe((data) => {
            this.categories = JSON.stringify(data);
            console.log("this.categories inside component" + this.categories);' and this shows data. My problem is still a data type issue as '<tr *ngFor="let category of categories; '  crashes with 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'categoryName' of undefined at'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the result of your service call is generic respectively not a known type in your application. To get rid of this error you have turn off type checks by using var when receiving the result in  the subscribe; And by declaring categoriesList of type "any"

Then you can use it in your app (html templates) as you are used to do!

See here the snippets:

```
    public categoriesList:any;

    ...
    this.dataService.getRecords('MT_Entity')
        .subscribe((data: any[]) => {
            var response: any = data;
            var resprecords = response.items;
            this.categoriesList = resprecords;
        }, err => {
          console.log(err);
    });
    ...
```

Comment: ok for using var and thank you for the information. It remains strange that I have to turn type check off for this to be resolved.

Comment: Object you get is of different type and not assignable. Thats the reason why.

Comment: Hello @Karl I am ok for Service side as I do not have the error any more but what happens component side ? In my constructor I have this.categories = categoryService.getCategories(); and categories "maps" to html elements. I am receiving an error : 'EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./CategoryComponent class CategoryComponent - inline template:20:24 caused by: self.context.getCategories is not a function
TypeError: self.context.getCategories is not a function
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_CategoryComponent0.detectChangesInternal' ...

Comment: @Philippe: categoryService.getCategories() returns an Observable; You are assigning an observerable; you have to assign the result of your service call to your variable in the subscribe callback.